# How do I see Samba groups?

Tags: server, samba

How can I see all groups in my Samba server? If possible, with users who belong to that group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Groups within samba are mapped over from the normal Unix groups used on your system. You can view these with the command.

```
sudo cat /etc/group
```

Comment: @MaxRian Share an upvote to show your appreciation.

Comment: @OXwivi not enough reputation:P

Comment: @MaxRian, there, reputation for you!

Answer (score 4):

To list Samba domain groups:

`sudo samba-tool group list`

If you want to see member users from a Group:

`sudo samba-tool group listmembers "Domain Admins"`

Reference: https://www.tecmint.com/manage-samba4-active-directory-linux-command-line/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Samba 4's Active Directory you should use the `net` command:

```
net rpc group list
```

To get a group's members list use:

```
net rpc group members GROUPNAME
```

To obtain help on the `group` command:

```
net group
```